# How can I show the first value of store on text field, in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, frontend

I'm new in ExtJS. I want to show store's first value on textfield. I researched but couldn't find it. How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have your store in `store` variable, your field in `field` and you'd like to set the property of "property" of the first record as the textfield's value:

```
field.setValue(store.getAt(0).get('property'));
```

You have the make sure the store has at least 1 record:

```
if (store.getCount()>0)
```